# Updating a multidimensional array using two 'for' loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm seeking to update the a league table by looping through a results array by player.  The user populates the results through a html table beforehand.

```
players=[];
var players=["A","B","C"];

Results=[];
var Results=[
  ["Home","F","A","Away"],
  ["A",,,"B"],
  ["A",,,"C"],
  ["B",,,"C"],
  ["B",,,"A"],
  ["C",,,"A"],
  ["C",,,"B"],
];

League=[];
var League=[
  ["Team","P","W","D","L","F","A","Pts"],
  ["A",,,,,,,],
  ["B",,,,,,,],
  ["C",,,,,,,]
];
```

I've tried using two for loops as follows:

```
var pld=0;
var wins=0;
var draws=0;
var loses=0;
var goalsF=0;
var goalsA=0;
var pts=0;


for (p = 0; p <= players.length; p++)
{

  for (i = 1; i < Results.length; i++)
  {
    if (Results[i][1]!= "")
    {
      if (Results[i][0]==players[p])
      {

        pld++;
        if (Results[i][1]>Results[i][2])
        {
          wins++;
          goalsF=+goalsF + +Results[i][1];
          goalsA=+goalsA + +Results[i][2];
          pts= +pts + 3;
        }
        else if (Results[i][1]<Results[i][2])
        {
          loses++;
          goalsF=+goalsF + +Results[i][1];
          goalsA=+goalsA + +Results[i][2];
        }
        else
        {
          draws++;
          goalsF=+goalsF + +Results[i][1];
          goalsA=+goalsA + +Results[i][2];
          pts++
        }
      }
    }
  }
  League[p][1]=pld;
  League[p][2]=wins;
  League[p][3]=draws;
  League[p][4]=loses;
  League[p][5]=goalsF;
  League[p][6]=goalsA;
  League[p][7]=pts;
}
```

Where the first two results are input, A's table values are correct but they're wrongly showing for B and C?

[image]

And when all six results are keyed on, again A's values are correct but B's and C's just accumulate?

[image]

I believe my problem is related to where I'm resetting the win, draws and losses etc counts. If I do this before the for loops (as shown above), results get counted twice,  if I do this inside, nothing is counted at all.

Any guidance appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a more object oriented way to do this?

Comment: Thanks octameter.  I'm open to different approaches but very much a novice still.  Can you share any links?

Comment: Can you add a header to your tables so that we know what you want to display

Comment: Cheers Chris.  Please excuse the position of the header but hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone's resposnse so far, I managed to find a solution - I  reset the count variables immediately after updating the league but is there a better solution?

```
    var pld=0;
    var wins=0;
    var draws=0;
    var loses=0;
    var goalsF=0;
    var goalsA=0;
    var pts=0;


    for (p = 0; p <= players.length; p++)
    {

      for (i = 1; i < Results.length; i++)
      {
        if (Results[i][1]!= "")
        {
          if (Results[i][0]==players[p])
          {

            pld++;
            if (Results[i][1]>Results[i][2])
            {
              wins++;
              goalsF=+goalsF + +Results[i][1];
              goalsA=+goalsA + +Results[i][2];
              pts= +pts + 3;
            }
            else if (Results[i][1]<Results[i][2])
            {
              loses++;
              goalsF=+goalsF + +Results[i][1];
              goalsA=+goalsA + +Results[i][2];
            }
            else
            {
              draws++;
              goalsF=+goalsF + +Results[i][1];
              goalsA=+goalsA + +Results[i][2];
              pts++
            }
          }
        }
      }
      League[p][1]=pld;
      League[p][2]=wins;
      League[p][3]=draws;
      League[p][4]=loses;
      League[p][5]=goalsF;
      League[p][6]=goalsA;
      League[p][7]=pts;

// Reset the 'count' variables here:      
      var pld=0;
      var wins=0;
      var draws=0;
      var loses=0;
      var goalsF=0;
      var goalsA=0;
      var pts=0;**
    }
```